# Table with many columns or many small tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I created a table where it has 30 columns.

```
CREATE TABLE "SETTINGS" (
  "column1" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
  ...
  "column30"
)
```

However, I can group them and create different table where they can have foreign keys to the primary table. Which is the best way to follow? Or the number of the columns is small so it's the same which way I will follow?

Comment: Depends on the type of data,  duplicates, nulls etc.

Comment: Depends on what each column is about. For example, if you have a table storing user information such as name,email, number, password, and more information about that user it would be wise to create different tables. A table that stores the contact information, and so on. Having a lot of columns eventually will result in slower querys.

Comment: The majority of the data type is `DOUBLE`, and then some `INTEGER` and `VARCHAR`. All the records will have values..

Comment: For 30 fields, I would say there is no problem with your structure, given that all the fields are SETTINGS and not relations between a setting and something else.

Comment: depend by your relational model

Comment: @Nat95 In that case you should be fine with 30 columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the data and the query you often do.

Best for one big table

- If you need to extract all the columns always
- If you need to update many fields at the same time
- If all the fields or quite all have not null values

Best for many little tables

- If the data are "sparse" it means not many columns have values you can imagine to split them in different tables and create a record in a child table only if not null values exists
- If you extract only few related fields at one time
- If you update only related fields at one time
- Better names for each column (for example instead of domicile_address and residence_address you can have two columns with named address in two tables residences and domiciles)

The problem is that generally you can use both solutions depending from the situation. A usage analysis must be done to choose the right one.

Comment: I got it. When I will  ask `settings` I will always want to get all the columns

Comment: @Nat95 if you need to get always all the columns probably the best is to have them on one big table. Consider to use many tables only for clarity if performances are not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If they really are named column1, column2....column30 then that's a fairly good indicator that your data is not normalized.

Following the rules of normalization should always be your starting point. There are *sometimes* reasons for breaking the rules - but that comes after you know what your data should look like.

Regarding breaking the rules.....there are 2 potential scenarios which *may* apply here (after you've worked out the correct structure and **done an appropriate level of testing with an appropriate volume of data**):

- Joins are expensive. holding parent/child relations in a single table can improve query performance where you are routinely selecting only both parent and child and retrieving individual rows
- unless you are using fixed width MyISAM tables, updating records can result in them changing size, and hence they have to relocated in the table data file. This is expensive and can have a knock on effect on retrieval.